# Jboss EAP 7 Logging format

Tags: java, logging, jboss-eap-7

I am working on JBoss EAP 7. I am using my own log4j2 instead of Jboss logging.
So I exlcuded them in the Jboss-deployment-structure.xml file.

```
<deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
     <!--
      Prevent that the server add automatically dependencies -->
      <!-- Exclude all logging dependencies so we can use log4j2 -->
      <exclusions>
         <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
         <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
         <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
         <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
         <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
         <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
         <module name="org.slf4j" />
         <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
      </exclusions> 
</deployment>
```

In My log4j2.xml file I mentioned pattern layout as below.

```
<Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%p|%d|%c|%m|%n" />
        </Console>
```

But When I start the application intially there is a class loading in which the logs are printing correctly like below.

```
DEBUG|2017-08-08 13:20:26,993|Default.com.test.StartClass|deleting directory: C:\eclipse\workspace\WEB-INF\templates
```

but later when Jboss server starts loading its subsystem it is adding stdout and adding some other stuff infront of my actual pattern.

```
13:39:06,997 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) INFO|2017-08-08 13:39:06,997|Default.com.test.AppXmlUnmarshaller|Unmarshalling took 342 milliseconds.
```

I don't why after excluding the subsystem also it is taking that pattern layout.
Please help me how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss EAP wraps both `stdout` and `stderr` in loggers. I assume you're using a `ConsoleAppender` which will write to `stdout`. If you want to avoid the standard pattern prefix you'd need to create a separate `console-handler` and assign it a pattern that only prints the message. Then create a `stdout` logger and assign the new `console-handler` to it with `use-parent-handlers` set to `false`. Something like the following CLI commands should do it.

```
/subsystem=logging/pattern-formatter=msg-only-format:add(pattern="%s%n")
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=stdout:add(named-formatter=msg-only-format, autoflush=true, target=System.out)
/subsystem=logging/logger=stdout:add(handlers=[stdout], use-parent-handlers=false)
```

Also just an FYI if you're excluding the logging subsystem you don't need those dependency exclusions. The logging subsystem is what adds those dependencies to your deployment.